# What can I do? sequelize isnull

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, isnull

[table] USER_INFO

```
user_id  |  user_name
a123     |  facebook
b123     |  google
c123     |  NULL
```

[query]

```
select isnull(user_name, user_id) as user_name from USER_INFO
```

[result]

```
user_name
facebook
google
c123
```

[sequelize] ???????

```
User.findAll({attributes: [
    user_id
    ,user_name
 ]
});
```

I want the same result, query = sequelize..

Answer (score 1):

Try using where operators:

```
User.findAll({where:{
    user_name:{[Op.ne]:null}
},{attributes: [user_id,user_name]
}});
```